# Отправка сообщения всем пользователям группы

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Здравствуйте.
Нужно делать следущие вещи:

1. Взять всех пользователей с группы или фан пэйдж страницы (лайки юзеров)
2. Взять их контактную информацию
3. Отправить всем им сообщение в фэйсбук.

Что возможно сделать с помощью фэйсбук апи? В документации у них я ничего не нашел.
Если первые два пункта я смогу парсить в ручную, то сообщения без апи как отправить - не представляю.

Помогите кто чем может, люди добрые.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Плохо искали. [liveMessage.send](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/liveMessage.send/)

и т.д в том же духе.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

>и т.д в том же духе.

Т.е. Вы имели ввиду, что все решается через фэйсбук апи, даже первые два пункта, я просто плохо ищу, верно?